# How to connect ov5642 camera module Pixel clock (8MHz) to imx6 quad

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, interrupt, imx6

I am using i.mx6quad with debian jessie (3.14.60-fslc-imx6-sr).

I want co connect ov5642 camera module with PARALLEL 8BIT interface (using 8gpios for data and 3 for control signals).
I wrote a linux kernel module to service interrupts from control signals. Interrupts from VSYNC and HREF signals are serviced properly but when I connect a PCLK (about 8MHz) signal which is much faster than HREF or VSYNC my linux hangs up untill I disconnect a wire with PCLK (everything stucks).
To connect PCLK I use GPIO90 (DISP1_DATA22) but I tried also with other gpios.

Now My question is which GPIO should I use to service such fast signals like PCLK properly or what can i do to avoid linux hang ups ??

I include a linux kernel module code that I use.

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/gpio.h>
#include<linux/interrupt.h>

static unsigned int VSYNC_gpio_number=79;
static unsigned int HREF_gpio_number=76;
static unsigned int PCLK_gpio_number=90;
static unsigned int VSYNC_irqNumber;
static unsigned int HREF_irqNumber;
static unsigned int PCLK_irqNumber;

static irq_handler_t VSYNC_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs);
static irq_handler_t HREF_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs);
static irq_handler_t PCLK_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs);


int __init camera_module_test_init(void){//init_module() 
    int result=0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: Initializing the GPIO_TEST LKM\n");
//VSYNC init
    if(!gpio_is_valid(VSYNC_gpio_number)){
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO TEST: invalid VSYNC GPIO\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
//HREF init
    if(!gpio_is_valid(HREF_gpio_number)){
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO TEST: INVALID HREF GPIO\n");
    return -ENODEV; 
    }
//PCLK init
    if(!gpio_is_valid(PCLK_gpio_number)){
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO TEST: INVALID PCLK GPIO\n");
    return -ENODEV;
    }

    //ledOn=true;
//VSYNC
    gpio_request(VSYNC_gpio_number,"sysfs");
    gpio_direction_input(VSYNC_gpio_number);    
    gpio_export(VSYNC_gpio_number,false);  // causes gpioX to appear in sysfs /sys/class/gpio/
//HREF
    gpio_request(HREF_gpio_number,"sysfs");
    gpio_direction_input(HREF_gpio_number);
    gpio_export(HREF_gpio_number,false);
//PCLK
    gpio_request(PCLK_gpio_number,"sysfs");
    gpio_direction_input(PCLK_gpio_number);
    gpio_export(PCLK_gpio_number,false);


    // GPIO numbers and IRQ numbers are not the same
//MAPPING   GPIO NUMBERS TO IRQ NUMBERS
//---------
    VSYNC_irqNumber = gpio_to_irq(VSYNC_gpio_number);
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: VSYNC signal is mapped to IRQ: %d\n",VSYNC_irqNumber);
    //
    HREF_irqNumber=gpio_to_irq(HREF_gpio_number);
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO TEST: HREF signal is mapped to IRQ: %d\n",HREF_irqNumber);
    //
    PCLK_irqNumber=gpio_to_irq(PCLK_gpio_number);
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO TEST: PCLK signal is mapped to IRQ: %d\n",PCLK_irqNumber);

    //requests an interrupt line
//VSYNC 
    result=request_irq(VSYNC_irqNumber,(irq_handler_t)VSYNC_gpio_irq_handler,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,"VSYNC_gpio_handler",NULL);
    if(result==0){  //if success
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The VSYNC interrupt request result is: %d\n",result);
        }   
        else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The VSYNC interrupt request FAIL !!! (%d)\n",result);  
    return result;  
    }
//HREF  
    result=request_irq(HREF_irqNumber,(irq_handler_t)HREF_gpio_irq_handler,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,"HREF_gpio_handler",NULL);
    if(result==0){ //if success
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The HREF interrupt request result is: %d\n",result);
    }
    else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The HREF interrupt request FAIL !!! (%d)\n",result);
    return result;  
    }
//PCLK
    result=request_irq(PCLK_irqNumber,(irq_handler_t)PCLK_gpio_irq_handler,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,"PCLK_gpio_handler",NULL);   
    if(result==0){// if success
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The PCLK interrupt request result is: %d\n",result);
    }
    else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The PCLK interrupt request FAIL !!! (%d)\n",result);   
    return result;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "MODULE LOADED.... WAITING FOR INTERRUPTION\n");   

    return result;
}

static void __exit camera_module_test_exit(void){ //cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "EXITING CAMERA_LKM_MODULE_TEST\n");

//unexporting GPIOs
    gpio_unexport(VSYNC_gpio_number);
    gpio_unexport(HREF_gpio_number);
    gpio_unexport(PCLK_gpio_number);
//freeing IRQs
    free_irq(VSYNC_irqNumber,NULL);
    free_irq(HREF_irqNumber,NULL);
    free_irq(PCLK_irqNumber,NULL);
//freeing memory
    gpio_free(VSYNC_gpio_number);
    gpio_free(HREF_gpio_number);
    gpio_free(PCLK_gpio_number);

    printk(KERN_INFO "GOODBYE world - MODULE CLOSED\n");
}


static irq_handler_t VSYNC_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs){
    printk(KERN_INFO "* VSYNC Interrupt on rising! *\n");

    return (irq_handler_t)IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static irq_handler_t HREF_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs){
    printk(KERN_INFO "-- HREF interrupt! on rising --\n");

    return (irq_handler_t)IRQ_HANDLED;  
}

static irq_handler_t PCLK_gpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq,void *dev_id,struct pt_regs *regs){
    printk(KERN_INFO "// PCLK interrupt! on rising //\n");

    return (irq_handler_t)IRQ_HANDLED;
}

module_init(camera_module_test_init);
module_exit(camera_module_test_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I can add that I am using hummingboard gate with available gpios shown in attached image.

[hummingboard gate available gpios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5vb5.jpg)

Comment: The driver *drivers/media/i2c/soc_camera/ov5642.c* already is in upstream. Use the kernel which has it, or backport one. In case you need to add another type of communication interface feel free to modify existing driver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andy but this side [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/media/i2c/soc_camera/?v=3.14) shows that ov5642 driver should be available in 3.14 kernel verision but i did some research and i didn't find it even after setting up linux headers with sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.14.y-fslc-imx6-sr. Command " find / -name ov5642 gives no output.

Comment: What are you expecting to find in **headers**?! I assume it uses standard media controller / video-for-linux API.